# How to use svn command line: "svn log -l 3" to show proper history?

Tags: svn

I work at a company for contracting work, and they use svn command line and text diff by ssh'ing to the Linux desktop.  For the command to show 3 log items:

```
svn log -l 3
```

I wonder why it doesn't show the history I just committed?  The file is in one of the sub-directories.

So for example, if I do a

```
svn log -l 3 foo/bar/abc.html
```

then the log history will show the commit I just did one minute ago.  But the first command line I posted, it will only show the log that is 10 days ago and committed by someone else.  Is there a way to make it work like Tortoise or Versions, so that it will show the log history for the current directory and down, or for the whole project?

Answer (score 1):

This is because your commit has created a mixed-revision working copy.

See the "Why does svn log Not Show Me What I Just Committed?" section of the svnbook here:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.history.html#svn.tour.history.log

It'll reference the "Updates and commits are separate" section which goes into more details on mixed-revisions.

You can either update your working copy with `svn update` before running the log command or you can use `svn log -l 3 -r HEAD:1` to bypass the default revision range being BASE:1 (and to see the current log without having to update your working copy first).